# i need a characters /letters dataset for matlab

Tags: neural-network, matlab, image-recognition

My final project is number plate recognition.i need a data set of A-Z characters and 0-9 letters. i donot find it on any website give me a data set or send me a link. i have to make a neural network in which i put that data set to train and test my data.

Comment: Use [pangol](http://www.pango.org/) to make the data-set yourself. Furthermore, take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35378691/5120235).

Comment: i am working on handwritten english characters recognition using matlab . i need training dataset of uppercase and lowercase letters. please please send me any one

Answer (score 1):

You can find car license plat [Here](https://github.com/Sardhendu/License-Plate-Detection)  or you can collect them from this [web site](http://www.worldlicenseplates.com) but it will take you  a while.